# How to set default mount point?

Tags: mount, restart

I have a drive on /dev/sda1 that's mounted to

```
/media/<username>/mydrive
```

Everytime I reboot my computer I have to execute the following two commands to change mount path:

```
sudo umount /media/<username>/mydrive
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/<username>/media/<username>/mydrive
```

How do I automate this? or change it so the default mount path can be:

```
/home/<username>/media/<username>/mydrive
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could edit the /etc/fstab file in a text editor like such as gedit or subl, or you could just do this:

1. Make sure the Hard Drive is connected.
2. Open **Disks**
3. Click on the Hard Drive you want to modify.
4. Click on the Partition you want to modify.
5. Click on the **gear icon**
6. Click on **Edit Mount Options**
7. Move the **Automatic Mount Options** slider to **Off**
8. Type in the path you want the Partition mounted too in the **Mount Point** text box.
9. Click the **OK** button.
10. Type in the super-user password.  This will make the necessary changes to the /etc/fstab file for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, forgot to mention i need shell commands since I can only connect via SSH. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you log in from a Linux machine with the -Y option, you should be able to just run the GUI application on your local machine.  1. Type ssh -Y user@remoteIPAddress  2.  Type gnome-disks to open the GUI app on your local machine, well actually it opens on the remote machine, but sends the GUI info to your local machine.

Comment: ok, this works. Ended up physically going into the machine.

Comment: following this in 2023 with Ubuntu 23 the slider in step 7 is now labeled "User Session Defaults".  I'd also add that once this is done, for the changes to take affect you should click the Stop icon to unmount (next to gear icon of step 5), then the Play icon to remount the drive.

Answer (score 1):

To mount automatically at boot time there is file `/etc/fstab` . In this file you specified which device should be mounted to mount point . As an example :

```
$ vim /etc/fstab
/dev/sda1 /home/USER-ID ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Replace USER-ID with your mount point and ext4 with your file system . For any information about more options in fstab see `man fstab` .

In systemD there is unit by the name of *mount* which supposed to be replaced with fstab . Try to mount with systemD may help :

```
cd /usr/lib/systemd/system
cp tmp.mount /etc/systemd/system
vim /etc/fstab
```

And take your added line out.

```
cd /etc/systemd/system
mv tmp.mount mydata.mount
vim mydata.mount
```

Edit these options:

- What=/dev/sda1
- Where=/home/USER-ID
- type=ext4
- options=defaults

umount old mounted partition.

```
systemctl deamon-reload
systemctl start mydata.mount
systemctl enable mydata.mount
```

Comment: doesn't work... "root account locked" is the error message

Comment: Using sunnyDaze's method, it auto generated this line in fstab, looks like i need all these extra things to make it work: /dev/sda1 /home/<username>/media/<username>/mydrive auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

Comment: I edited answer with systemD unit. Try this .

Comment: @NinjaCowgirl that's looks fstab format . Hope it works .